# How to join two tables in hibernate using HQL

Tags: hibernate, join, hql

I want to join two tables using `hibernate`. For example the tables are like the following..

```
Person(personId,name, mobile)
Mobile(mobileId, mobileNumbers)
```

How to join them using HQL?

Comment: Join means what is target.Are you trying to insert in two tables

Answer (score 0):

See the below line. I'm assuming that the mobile property as Mobile class in the person class.

```
from Person as person left outer join person.mobile
```

Comment: But if both of them are different tables then how to join them?

Comment: from Person as person, Mobile as mobile where person.mobile = mobile.mobile 
I think this is the only way of doing in hibernate. as you cannot join unrelated tables. I've been through the same, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I understood your question somewhat, If you are trying to add something in two table at the same time , the answer is below.

- In hibernate have following types of components to implement
  connection between two tables
- This tutorial [one-to-one](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-one-1.html) implements connection between two
  tables.

*See Also starts learns with the Hibernate kick of tutorials*

- [Hibernate basic tutorial](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-tutorial/hibernate-tutorial.html)
- [Hibernate video tutorial](http://javabrains.koushik.org/p/hibernate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Tables:
Person(personId,name, mobile)
Mobile(mobileId, mobileNumbers)

HQL for hibernate:
from Person p, Mobile b